# How would get/edit data from a text file?

Tags: javascript, text-files

I have a specific website where i would like to see how many views a certain page gets, with a text file being edited every time a person clicks on the page.
I've tried doing this myself but it did not work out,
I am not sure if i have done anything wrong here myself since i am still new to javascript.

```
var viewC = FileReader.readAsText('./views.txt');

var views = viewC + 1
var viewFile = " " + views +" ";

function download(content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
}
download(viewFile, 'views.txt', 'text/plain');
```

For a more detailed description of what i would like to happen : "When the user goes to the page, the code will run and add a new value to the text file. The new value is +1 of the old value that is there."
Expected result -
TXT file before  
TXT file after a person views it  `1` 
TXT file after the second view `1  2`
Or if it is possible to remove the old number and add the new number

Comment: Handle this from the server. The client does not have access to files on the server without the server explicitly giving access. Besides it will be easier if to track which pages get requested by the client and update your text file based on that. I would also recommend JSON (or even a database for that matter) instead of a textfile. Your code can read and modify that more easily.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I am not really sure how i would do that, i wanted to do a txt file because i thought it would be a bit easier

Comment: Server logs is the easiest solution

Comment: @YetNT a text file is fine as well. Disregard my comment about JSON. But the server part still stands.